# Setting Width of control relative to screen resolution in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I am unable to set the size of border control relative to screen resolution.

I want to specify width of Border to 80% of the screen resolution [width wise only]. But I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to put your border in a Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--80% column-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <!--20% column-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Column="0"
            Background="Red"></Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1"
            Background="Yellow"></Border>
</Grid>
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I just realised I did not read your question properly. You are talking about screen resolution. My example sets the first column of the grid to 80% of the browser window size. If it is screen resolution you want I think you will have to use javascript to get the values and then use code to set your object to the correct size:

```
var width= HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.availWidth");
var height= HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.availHeight");
```